# Problem importing txt file data with pandas

Tags: pandas, import

```
df = pd.read_csv("AVG.txt")
df
```

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte**

I'm a beginner i'm trying to interpret some data with python and i ran into this error trying to load the file

This is the file I am trying to upload:
[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gmE1R7Et5EcCYslibfOAAikYZX-VHMPt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an encoding issue, try

```
df = pd.read_csv("AVG.txt",encoding="utf-16")
```

You may also try using the basic `open()` function and parse it later on

Comment: it worked! a thousand thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file is a .txt file. If you save it as a .csv should work fine (e.g. copy into Excel and use Save As). Just tried it and its worked.

Comment: I can't do it, by default the program exports to txt unfortunately

Comment: Then best to go with Grall's answer. I agree with his/ her assessment of the issue. (you might also want to accept his/ her answer as the solution/ upvote if you can for the rep points and for others with similar issues).